# There is no shell for current user

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I am facing a very strange error. I was using **fish shell** with **oh-my-fish** (https://github.com/bpinto/oh-my-fish) and I tried to change my command line to **bash** using:

```
$ chsh -s /bin/bash [my_username]
```

after that, the command prompt stack! And after a restart there is no shell at all. Command line opens but **no command works**. Since there is no shell available I do not know how to bring back any available shell. There is no error anywhere.

I tried to edit manually the /etc/passwd and change the shell there but still no luck. Also, run the chsh command with another session from another admin user. Nothing happens.

Using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: If bash works OK from another user account, and your login shell is set to bash, then isn't it more likely that there is some *configuration* setting that's at fault? Perhaps try restoring a 'clean' .bashrc and .profile to your account from the /etc/skel/ directory?

Comment: @steeldriver Your suggestion was true. Actually it was a config error after I have removed rvm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @steeldriver: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 0):

Answer copied from comments:

If bash works OK from another user account, and your login shell is set to bash, then isn't it more likely that there is some configuration setting that's at fault? Perhaps try restoring a 'clean' `.bashrc` and `.profile` to your account from the `/etc/skel/` directory!